# Meaning of "niche" in "he knows the niches of this or that genre"

Tags: meaning, nouns, meaning-in-context, sentence

> He knows the niches of this or that genre.

Which meaning is intended here?

1. He is a master at every genre and knows everything about them.
2. He has a shallow knowledge about every genre.

Comment: That seems likely to be (1), but questions involving ambiguities can only be answered with all the context.

Comment: here is the full sentence:
"But there are professionals who write (and think) very amateurishly and amateurs who know more about the niches of this or that genre than any professional ever will."

Comment: I would say it is more likely to mean (2), but agree more context is needed.

Comment: OK, with added context it clearly means (1). But it's poorly expressed.

Comment: So can we use it as a noun for the word "Expert"? for example in another sentence like this: "I think that anyone writing serious criticism is essentially talking to a niche. " can we say niche means an expert or does it mean a minority of people?

Comment: Here "this or that" means that some amateurs know more about niches of /some/ genres than any professional. Whether this statement applies to all genres separately is unclear.

Comment: A niche refers to a rather narrow subtopic within a wider topic, or in your example, a specific group of people (say, those interested in a specific topic) rather than to a general audience.

Comment: I believe the original author was reaching for the word ***nuances*** (and missed it). :)

Comment: I’m very confused here—not by the question, but by the number of people who find this sentence confusing or badly worded. A _niche_ is a recess in a wall, a place that is harder to light than the rest of the wall, a sort of ‘corner on a straight wall’, if you will. _Niches_ in the context of “knowing the niches of a genre” is very obviously (to me) basically the same metaphor as “knowing every nook and cranny in a genre”. I cannot think of any way of making the sentence mean anything dealing with _shallow_ knowledge at all. How did those who found this likely come to that interpretation?

Comment: It's simply a typo, or, the person is a completely incompetent writer.  What he was thinking of is the common phrase "knows the ins and outs of the game".

Comment: Hey Janus - your comment should be put in a niche and sealed over :)  It's a typo, or just an idiot writing.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet,  “knowing the niches of a genre” obviously refers to knowing the grounds and bounds of a genre; no deep knowledge is required for that.  IOW, the phrase says nothing at all about depth of knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the full sentence

> But there are professionals who write (and think) very amateurishly and amateurs who know more about the niches of this or that genre than any professional ever will.

it clearly aims at something like your first proposed meaning, but that's not very well expressed.

It doesn't mean he is a master at every genre. It means for some particular genre(s), the amateur may know (some) things in more depth or of a more recondite nature than a so-called master, but does not necessarily mean the amateur's knowledge is more exhaustive or even useful than a master's. The sentence is ambiguous at best.